# Comparator configuration that doesn't provide output change

Tags: comparator

I've [this](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgbJiRsEUQ0eWmEID84KNFFNssbFho1MkQpBwZiomJBTYw8A4Z1Q2Adx59wxfijxCw1k+ezZRKFDQF2BHpz1c+nrw2vpBmXvaOtvaqftHgsZj8IlRh5vHunhkIWuHZbjkChWkCGMmJhSlx3lXxYIrVQiiFGWUmAE5FolUO5anIcGydzQXdUcUDYcM1DfF4-fqD001t8S5ak2wA5jx4WZy7WW2p2xH+bt6uQic7c1TxNNcmAEpWfeC2Cf38B2BSSH9CEhUtAEGxXr0uh8mhMflRAQD-uBQRg1JpsEQNI9NFpQeDDuAMKJsHtoVByQdZPR+jAweYaCIxEIaJomR0zpDMm9yYsSlzOb4uXzBYLvEK8r4EFFvFL+MLPDl7pLHFMzorAhRYvD4OEGaIEETaKyDblXiSFQ1zUaNlRKdBqeTafjIYRfGBPq7PPdaPCpMjuii0YQMYQsXgcZIwRDHHx7J9Y+S4f7kyCwbdvIomhnGTczqist4cDbTlbVEJSwcTssQIQDvF8+SXEs1e6zpnG7hVSMa27HJ6eTrhoUE5CE9rBulvP34rWTpOhAn4ghW3y2ovh58+VPBYV+1uF9KhHu8jLPkkKJuTwvEqfruF1hRHMFH3L7wFZWqVffLOql1qOFwFj8Cawj6oaEAwNIVLuJAGJ4GAGA5HghBAtcsC6BBbAAPa0Dwco+sQC6SHAejNOSohBDW5E8AIEG0Tw2G0EgtYUlwRHaLB7oAlRNBIPQZH3HxXiJuWbBAA) two configuration of a comparator in falstad:

[image: Comparator circuit]

Looking at plot I have a voltage difference between + and - , but I don't have an output change. I've tried to find out why, especially on datasheet, but nothing. Can someone explain me why happening this?

I've tried this also on with an MCP634 on a breadboard with the same behavior as simulation.

Comment: Why have you built this circuit, what's its intended function? Please edit your question and add a description at the top. At the moment, it appears as just a pointlessly bad design so we'd need to know what its objectives are.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator is actually a 741 op-amp and that op-amp doesn't work very well when operated with a 3.3V supply.

I've modified your circuit [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgbJiRsEUQ0eWmEID84KNFEsU0MNkLziYDAWII8hejEgpsYeIaO6obAO48%204YvxR4hYG6YvYFAlDQH33nyOZ5uKB6WtsF%20FnYOTpHghFThXg5xAhj8IvH%20MUGeWQiiCbmiKHkCJQWpsVTFounOiZX1YDS%20md7V9Zj8fgBOpTXJjmnJVAZwbL3t7YN9UMhjE95NOd548XM9HRUxrvnrbADmPHg5nEc5FRmH24HeCkKX9av1NPemAErWQyN2DVW0VEgkPFoAg2B9plMfu0-qdAeAQRhIBhiFoiMiXij8iCwWdwBhRNhjuAfmtTmAurMYKCLDQRGIhDQUfTTAsoqFPNMRvBMsEIcFsnUBUK2mEeZ4ENFvBKumKKMkBdKWfU8lVgirZqMErTRAh8bQmbr8jjCeLmrjGbsqKdsNBtJTseCnIReT9nb4BP94TUpPDdUiUdg0cQMYQsaDHfw%20A4flHZvwyT6wD7gaCrt5mkIYtrKQd6ojlkIcJbcyaQHEhKXCKcMqyy6cYvnZq55sryc8Xk3cBt2m7PmWwnsJiVY9NY1yxhFvL2YlWMpOhLGYgg2%20VI1DhyTWkJpyVewUpZLt6L5xQoRUx1u5VUpZuXG5FbxI04EjsKIe3zKXFZ1UvhhwuCEFB6tmhoSDA0g2oG5I0MUxyQDQhAYB2Oh6BAfgAPa0DwFKcMQmbAnA%20jFLMoiePQuwEgIaFUTwbCYTQSBVrMuELpIhHkkgECkUg9DEVUPFeHGFZsEAA) in a few ways:

1. Changed the supply for the first 741 to +12V.
2. Modified the input signals to be 5V with a 5V offset.

The second change ensures that the inputs are a few volts away from the supply rails.

With these changes the output oscillates between 11.8V and 1V.

Falstad has a comparator which works much better. In [this circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgbJiRsEUQ0eWmEID84KNFEsw0YghoYwkMIszFe3GJBTZl8A4f6Q2Adx59wxfijxCw1qGZ7ZRKFDQF2BHp%20eyuPp68Nr4m5rb2jpHghFThXvZxAhj8IvHOMe6eWQiiCblueQLFBamxVCjF6X6JFXWqngXeVW4t5SYATiWiNQ5pyVT6XT2j-aND8GzdMY11ePHIcNN1mDbeAflLJgDmPHg5nPs5HU57MZt1rkIZ594LdTQ3TgBKVgNDtvWVtFRISPFoAg2G9xq1wF9wT8jv9wECMJAMMRCNgiEinsj8kCQcdwBhRNgDhDnlQjmBjFBJMDzDQRGIhDRkfSnDNvGDfONJssIhzor5srUBUKWmFMr4ENFvBLjGLPHlKuLHCMYvKghRBttnLTRAh8bQmbr8jjGTryfrRDRCE1KUdsNB6IsYMDQY5CByvm7rfwyVI4b14YjkajCOi8JiqTjxnx7F9o5TvUNfbItk62HcGU9HnTbnUETlvDgU2ncXEhITPFbHSsYpXc5BrQFlqyhAgzTEaJmqI3lcVPe8QH2uT2dV8o18h5lvH2a0dmi3IVKzWV%20HHwXG5wP%20b3RREpZKhIPJ-OhGsKOOj%20rKlLz-5AtKLCulc5LveVU--JZVSrBhwVA%20KHq2oAb0IB4AAOgAzmACCQSwMFQYYkCQbISi6MoVoYWGeQ0JBMAYHQlCNgiDi0goyGGFAkFoORiHwOAuErCaFBmkxhqUsMbAAPa0DwFKcMQJ6AnAehVJSFo8AOYkSSgECVBA2BcbQSBWjaXAtpIwnkkgEAWkg9CiZUelePGZaKR61r8dwAKwJAbpIDYxkKUAA) I've modified the second 741 to use the comparator which needs a pull-up to output a high voltage. The output is shown in the third scope and you'll see it oscillates between 0 and 3.3V.

Comment: In fact, using MCP634 that is suitable with 3V3 and it's rail-to-rail perform like in 741 simulation. I've a difference between + and - but the output doesn't switch. Is something related to internal op.amps Vgs where difference between + and - should be > than internal Vgs?

Comment: I would try lifting your input signals a little above ground (like a couple hundred mV) and see what happens. It is possible the comparator doesn't function correctly with inputs near or at GND.